# Is there a hack to wash leather off without using a professional leather cleaner service?

Tags: cleaning

I have bought a pillow that dyes stuff around and it has dyed the white leather sofa.

[image]

**Is there a hack to wash leather off without using a professional leather cleaner service?**

Answer (score 2):

I know of two things that work well for cleaning leather, however, I cannot guarantee success, as I have no way of knowing the colour agent used in your pillow...

You need a weak degreasing agent, as acetone and ethanol are way too harsh on leather. You *can* use these agents on real leather, but it should only be done as a last resort, and ONLY if you have leather grease handy (to replace the fats that the acetone/ethanol pulled out).

One solution is **toothpaste**, but this is not suitable for large areas, only smaller areas with hard-to-remove stains (like a wine spill).
As toothpaste is a *polishing agent*, you'll need to seal up the surface with leather grease or similar

Another is **pre-canned shaving foam** (The cheapest you can find will do fine), which not only contains some diluted alcohol solution, but also lots of moisturizing agents. 
This makes it good for use as a large scale cleaner for leather, that's very good for lots of different stains and miscolorations (eg. nicotine). A neat side-effect is that it shines the leather up for a while.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, try [saddle soap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GT2SCU8).
2. If that doesn't work, use mild soaps, such as [oil soap](http://www.murphyoilsoap.com/home).
3. Finally, at the risk of damaging the leather surface, you could use solvents **outdoors, away from flames, warm car parts and other sources of ignition**, starting with ethanol, and then ethyl ether (in motor starting fluid), acetone and xylene. These may very well remove the white coloring of the leather, so you'll need to apply a white leather polish afterwards.
4. Finish up with a bit of [neatsfoot oil](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003IJ0N7A) to restore leather suppleness.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my experience stuffs like soap, ethanol, acetone etc. wouldn´t help you too much. Actually, you can try but you should use too much pressure with your hands to get minimum results visible by eyes.

To remove dyes (or i.e. safely remove coffee stains) from leather, I will suggest to you to use **toothpaste**. It is cheap and effective, and you should´t be worry about any damage - your leather is white, so probably nothing will goes wrong, you can´t bleached white leather sofa.

[Here](http://www.rd.com/home/16-unexpected-ways-to-use-toothpaste) you can check toothpaste uses. Even [they](http://www.couponsherpa.com/blog/35-uses-for-toothpaste-that-dont-involve-your-teeth/) recommended to use those which is free of bleaching and whitening agents, from my experience is better toothpaste *which contains* whitening effect.

Answer (score 0):

Buy some cheap degreaser (Simplegreen, LA's Totally Awesome, ZEP, etc), and gently scrub with a damp rag. Then use some cheap leather conditioner (